# Why are quotation marks omitted from this passage from a book from 1897?

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, omissibility

In William James's *The Will to Believe*, he writes:

> After all, though, you will say, Why so much ado about a matter concerning which, however we may theoretically differ, we practically agree?

Later, he writes:

> ...while Huxley exclaims, "My only consolation lies in the reflection...

The whole book seems pretty carefully edited, so I'm inclined to think that the omission of quotation marks in the first quote is intentional.

I would guess that he omitted them because the quote was never actually spoken by the reader. But I've looked through the *Cambridge History of the English Language Vol. 4  1776-1997*, the Wikipedia articles on quotation and quotation marks, and skimmed the books on puncutaion *Shady Characters* and *Making a Point* to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea when some authors do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of style, and *The Chicago Manual of Style* addresses this at:

> **13: Quotations and Dialogue**
> **13.43: Unspoken discourse**
>  Thought, imagined dialogue, and other internal discourse (also called interior discourse) may be
> enclosed in quotation marks or not, according to the context or the
> writer’s preference.
> <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of Style*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch13/psec043.html) (login required)</sub>

Since what “you will say” hasn’t been said yet, it’s unspoken discourse.

Some editors who eschew quotation marks in these situations will style the unspoken words in italics, like this:

> After all, though, you will say, *Why so much ado about a matter
> concerning which, however we may theoretically differ, we practically
> agree?*

Comment: Well done approach.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer. From *The Cambridge Dictionary of the English Language*:

> ##### Absence of overt indication
>
> Direct reported speech – in the broad sense of the term – is not always marked as such by
> punctuational means, especially when it is a matter of thought or interior monologue:
>
> > i *Where can she be?, he wondered.*
> >
> > ii *I bet she’s missed the train, he thought.*
>
> In texts consisting of dialogue, it is common practice just to give the speaker’s name
> followed by a colon or dash.